# Google Analytics opt-out by default (optional opt-in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, google-analytics

I have the following code below – but I'm struggling to find a way to make it disabled by default and only run if the user opts in (and remembers as it currently does). Also I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without the `location.reload(true)` – any further thoughts?

```
<div id="google_analytics"></div>

<script>

    var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X';
    var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
        window[disableStr] = true;
        console.log('GA is disabled');
    }
    // Opt-out function
    function gaOptout() {
        document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
        window[disableStr] = true;
        location.reload(true);
        console.log('GA is disabled');
    }
    // Opt-in function
    function gaOptin() {
        document.cookie = disableStr + '=false; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;';
        window[disableStr] = false;
        location.reload(true);
        console.log('GA is active');
    }

    if (window[disableStr] == true) {
        document.getElementById("google_analytics").innerHTML = 'You are opt-out from Google Analytics. <a href="javascript:gaOptin()">Opt-in</a>';}
    else {
        document.getElementById("google_analytics").innerHTML = 'This page is using <a href="http://analytics.google.com/">Google Analytics</a>. <a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Opt-out</a>';
    }

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', gaProperty, 'auto');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Any news on this ?